# angular pass current object to ng-options get undefiend

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

Im trying to get the current object on ng-change with ng-options and i get undefiend

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="currentDrawResults" ng-options="(draw.drawDate | date:'MMM d, y' ) for draw in lot.lastDraws track by draw.drawDate" ng-change="changeDraw(draw)">
 </select>
```

I was trying some answers from this site but still dont work.
whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change  `ng-change="changeDraw(draw)"`  to `ng-change="changeDraw(currentDrawResults)`

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope) {



  $scope.lot = {
    lastDraws: [{
        drawDate: "2011-10-28T09:30:24.673Z"
      }, {
        drawDate: "2012-09-28T09:30:24.673Z"
      }, {
        drawDate: "2014-05-28T09:30:24.673Z"
      },




    ]
  };

  $scope.changeDraw = function(draw) {
    alert(draw.drawDate)
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="fCtrl">


    <select class="form-control" ng-model="currentDrawResults" ng-options="(draw.drawDate | date:'MMM d, y' ) for draw in lot.lastDraws track by draw.drawDate" ng-change="changeDraw(currentDrawResults)">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```